# How to make changes to the dynamically created form fields into the Database with php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have created an admin panel through which I can add product categories and remove. It dynamically adds new field when add button is pressed and removes the field when remove button is pressed. The thing is, I am having problem making change in the database.

For instance ,say I already have 2 categories. I log into the admin panel. Now my question is, how to I have those two categories already displayed there, and how do I have them removed by clicking the remove button?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="product_category" class="container tab-pane active">
        <form action="one.php">
          <div class="form-row">
                <div class="product-category col-sm-12 my-2">
                  <div class="card col-sm-12">
                    <div class="card-title"><h3 class="text-center">Categories</h3></div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <div id="categories" class="form-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" id="add_cat_btn">Add Category</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block" id="remove_cat_btn">Remove Category</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
      </div>
```

**Jquery:**

```
  var cat_count=0;


$(document).on("click","#add_cat_btn",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("clicked");
    cat_count++;
    //$(this).before('<div id="cat'+cat_count+'"><div class="card my-2"><div class="card-body"><input type="text" name="cat_title[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Category Name" required><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="content" required><input type="file" class="form-control" required></div></div><button class="btn btn-success my-2">Submit</button></div>');
    $(document).find("#categories #add_cat_btn").before('<div id="cat'+cat_count+'"><div class="card my-2"><div class="card-body"><input type="text" name="cat_title[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Category Name" required><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="content" required><input type="file" class="form-control" required></div></div><button class="btn btn-success my-2">Submit</button></div>');

  });

  $('#remove_cat_btn').on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("removed");
    $('#categories').find('#cat'+cat_count).remove();
    cat_count--;
  });
```

Comment: Do you want to remove from Database also?.

Comment: Yes............

Comment: Then you have to use Ajax for loading data & on removing data.

Comment: Are you saying you want these categories loaded using AJAX or when the page runs and therefore placed in the page by PHP?

Comment: when the page loads the saved cats should be there and I should be able to delete each individually

Comment: Well you can do that with PHP on the server OR AJAX calls from that page. But I am assuming you mean to do it with PHP

Comment: Is your HTML in a `.php` file?